# Published React Native app pulls changes from private repository

Tags: android, ios, git, react-native, bitbucket

I've encountered a very mysterious and baffling phenomenon in the process of publishing a React Native app to both the Apple App Store and the Google Play Store.  It seems like witchcraft.

<s>The app, which we have already published on both stores, *updates every time we push changes to our private repository.*</s>

**EDIT**: The app, which we have already published on both stores, *updates SOME OF THE TIME (not every time) we push changes to our private repository.*

For example, let's say the app started out with page A and page B.  We publish the app, we'll call it "Witchcraft", to both app stores.  We then push an update to our private repository (on BitBucket) that includes the addition of page C.  The next day, someone (outside of the company) downloads our app from one of the app stores (without cloning our repository), and their install of "Witchcraft" includes page C.

What in the world is going on?

Here are some details:

- The app was developed in React Native.
- We used Expo for development and testing of the app.
- We host our repository using BitBucket.
- We are NOT developing in the master branch.
- New users, when they install the app from either play store, seem to see ALMOST all the changes we've pushed to the repository, BUT...
- There is one property of the repository that users do NOT acquire in their fresh installation - their installation correctly points to the production database (for retrieving user info, etc) instead of the development database, which is what is referenced in what is pushed to the repository.
- We have NOT updated the builds on the app stores, so we do not expect these changes to appear in the app store builds.

We are very concerned because we do not want breaking changes being reflected in the production app.

We haven't the slightest idea what is going on.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that you have OTA updates enabled, in your app.json add the following:

```
{
  "updates": {
    "enabled": false,
  }
}
```

Also check if at any point of the process you are doing `expo publish` maybe in git hook?